# Android voice recognition with screen off?

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I hoped that I would find answer in old questions but I didn't found anything. I'm trying to use *Android RecognizerIntent* from `VoiceRecognition.java` example. I change button for bluetooth signal and everything is working till the screen is on. If the screen is off `voice recognition` is not working. Is this because activity has no focus?

Do you have any solutions for that?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this because activity has no focus?

- Yes. If you want your stuff to persist through the screen off you'd have to put it [into a service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Comment: Thanks for fast answer, but can I call recognizerIntent to service? I think the only posibility is to call startActivityForResults().

Comment: So if I had a service with voice recognition implemented into it (the default class) and I turned my screen off, would the voice recognition still work?